# How to install flash socket policy on server Centos?

Tags: centos, cross-domain-policy, flashsocket

What should i do to install flashpolicyd from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html on Centos. Installation from Python_init folder and `./install.sh start` ?. Which step is install it ?

Thanks Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try PHPDaemon (http://daemon.io/docs/ru/#servers/flashpolicy) async fp server